# How to test a RollBack in a DataJPATest

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, integration-testing

Have a service class with a method annotated `@Transactional`. It does insert some data (entityA), than when adding next data (entityB) I'm expecting it to rollback first data inserted.

Just adding `@Transactional` already solve for manually testing.
Here is a pseudo implementation of service:

```java
public class EntityAService {
    private EntityARepository repository;
    private EntityBService serviceEntityB;

    @Transactional
    public void persistComplexData(ComplexData data) {
        EntityAData entity = data.getAData();
        repository.create(entity); 

        EntityBData entityB = data.getBData();
        serviceEntityB.insert(entityB); // Will throw exception and rollback entire method.
    }
}
```

For testing I'm using `@DataJPATest`, in it docs it says

> By default, tests annotated with @DataJpaTest are transactional and roll back at the end of each test.

So my test looks like this:

```java
@DataJpaTest
public class EntityAIntegrationTest {
    EntityAService service;
    EntityARepository repository;

    @Test
    public void createEntityBShouldNotCreateEntityA() {
        // Before alredy has one from test setup, next insert should fail cause conflics.
        assertThat(repository.findAll()).hasSize(1);

        ComplexData data = ComplexData.builder()
            ...
            .build();

        assertThrows(InternalValidationException.class, () -> service.persistComplexData(data));

        assertThat(repository.findAll()).hasSize(1); // <== Should be ok, but returning 2

    }
}
```

Tried to add `TestTransaction.start()`, but I'm getting error says that should finish existent transaction before initializing a new one.

PS: When running just *createEntityBShouldNotCreateEntityA* test, it works as suppose to. When running together with others get 2 instead of 1. Get this results when running with multiple even when changing *createEntityBShouldNotCreateEntityA* to be first test to run.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see from your test, the exception thrown is an `InternalValidationException` which is a checked exception (I can't be sure since you have not provided the package name).

When you use the  `@Transactional` annotation it does NOT rollback for checked exceptions.

Try to do something like this on your `persistComplexData(..)` method.

`@Transactional( rollbackFor = InternalValidationException .class)`